# Format a Label bound to display 200 characters followed by three dots

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I am trying to format a label to display 250 characters only followed by three dots, the control is bound to a field in a DB:

```
   <asp:Label ID="lbl_biography" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Biography")%>'   />
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question, and you don't show you've even thought about a basic approach as to how you can achieve your goal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Text='<%# CutText(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Biography"), 250)%>'
```

codebehind:

```
protected string CutText(object text, int length)
{
    if (DBNull.Value == text || text == null) return "";
    string txt = text.ToString();
    if (txt.Length <= length) return txt;
    return txt.Substring(0, length) + " ...";
}
```

Comment: Awesome Tim thanks a million!!!